# How does an IoT client report a changed property to the IoT Hub?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I'm using the azure-iot-sdk-c library for an iot device to talk to an IoT hub. I use IoTHubDeviceClient_LL_SetDeviceTwinCallback() to register a callback function in my client code that gets called whenever a device twin state property changes. In that code, I modify my device's properties and call IoTHubDeviceClient_LL_SendReportedState() to notify the hub that I did the changes that were requested.

But what happens if someone walks into the room where my device lies and changes one of those properties. My device code gets a notification of that property change but I would like to use that opportunity to let the IoT hub know that a property changed. How do I do that? There is no "set_desired_property" in the client sdk.

Answer (score 0):

You would send it back as a reported state. For example, if the device is monitoring a light and someone physically turns it off then the light's state is off. You send that as the light's reported state.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually doing that. And it seems that it works sometimes and sometimes not. I've yet to figure out in which scenarious, but it's probably related to when both server and client are changing properties because sometimes a property gets into "synching". I'm guessing that the server is insisting a particular property value the client wants something else and the server wants to have the final word or something. Perhaps there is some callback I need to take care of to let the server know that the client actually changed the property and now the client can change it at will?

Comment: I can reproduce the error like this: If the server sets a property to 1, then the client doesn't seem to be able to set the same property to 0 - the property goes into "synching" mode. Perhaps 0 means the same as null or something? But if the server sets the property to 0, then the client can change it back and forth.

Comment: Please .... so basically it seems that if a server sets a particular property to 1, the client can't change it to 0. But if the server sets it to 0, the client can change it back and forth. Does anyone know if the value 0 is some special value? Btw. the only possible values are 0 and 1.

Comment: Ok, I did more test. It doesn't seem to be related to 0 being a special value. What it is is this: Who decides what a property's value should be - the server or the client? I sometimes get into "synching" state of a property where the server has asked for a property change, the client has sent the correct reported property - and then the client wants the change the property and the server goes - no, I asked for another value and will the set the state to "synching" Can anyone please help? Who is the boss for property changes, the client or the server? They should both have a saying, IMO.